# Thread Invalid Access Error in SWT

Tags: multithreading, swt

Could you let me know the reason for this error in SWT 
"org.eclipse.swt.SWTException" Invalid Thread access ?
And How to fix such errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SWT you can access GUI resources only from the display thread. For example when setting the text in a org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text control you must already be in the display thread or call

```
        final Text text = ...;
        Display.getCurrent().syncExec(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                text.setText("test");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Finally,I got My problem solved.Your explanation helped me figure out the solution to my problem.While writing SWT applications,we need to take care of not accessing the UI elements and updating them in the non-UI thread.

Answer (score 4):

It happens when you try to act upon an interface item from a thread that's not the UI thread.

To run a code on the UI thread you have to use a Runnable and ask the display thread to run it.  This way:

```
Display.getDefault().syncExec( new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do your job here
    }
} );
```

As stated by the syncExec method javadoc,

> the thread which calls this method is suspended until the runnable completes.

Also, you might check the asyncExec method.

Comment: Finally,I got My problem Resolved.Your explanation helped me figure out the solution to my problem.